# using quiver in python to plot a 3d vector

Tags: python

Super simple question, I know, but it's my first day using python and have to learn to use it quickly.
I'd like to use quiver(it has to be quiver) to draw 3D vector.
to make it simple, if I want to draw the vector (1,1,1) and see it like in the following picture(in the right directions of course), how can I do it?
this is what I've been trying to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.quiver(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, scale=1, color='g')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`plt.quiver` only works for 1D and 2D arrays. You should use `mplot3d` to show your figure in 3 dimensions:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 0.8)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 0.8)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 0.8)
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, length = 0.5, normalize = True)
plt.show()
```

I recommend you read the documentation on [pyplot.quiver](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver) and [axes3d.quiver](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.quiver).